# shell script error status and syntax checking

Tags: shell, syntax

I have written a shell script and I am using few commands like `rm`, `ls`, etc. In case where those commands fails , I am checking the return status '$?' . But If the script has some syntax error, how can I get the error status of it ? Basically I am going to source this script from another script using the 'source' command. So if the script which is sourced has any syntax error I want to display that in console. Is there any way to get that status ? In shell I executed the script with syntax error and I got the error like 'missing [' , but when I executed `echo $?` its returning 0 as the status, is this the behavior ? How can I get the status if the script has some syntax error or not ?

Comment: `source` executes the commands of another script in the context of the current shell, so you get statuses of commands.
If you want to see the sh/bash exit status, use `sh script; echo $?`

Comment: Oops, it does not solve the problem, the subsequent commands are still executed

Comment: So, basically you need permanent error checking like `ret=$?; [ $ret -eq 0 ] || exit $ret`

Comment: You can run your shell with `#!/bin/bash -e`. It will then stop on error.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the syntax of a shell script using the `-n` option prior to sourcing:

```
bash -n somescript  # Works also for sh, ksh, zsh et al.
```

will tell you if somescript is syntactically okay without actually running it. In a program:

```
if bash -n somescript; then
   . somescript
else
   printf '%s\n' "Uh-oh, somescript is not syntactically correct." >&2
fi
```